# How to remove a selected row from a table when using KnockoutJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am simply binding a list of observable objects to a TR inside an html table. When the user selects a row(only one can be selected), i want that selected row or observable object to be removed from the observable array. I have the remove working but it's completely ignoring whether the row is selected or not. I am using a flag on each row to determine whether they are checked or not but the value is always true...even if you uncheck the checkbox on the row which is why it removes them all. Can someone please shed light on the below knockout setup...days of research and testing but KO just hates me :(

```
            <table class="accountGroups" id="tblAccountGroups">
            <tr>
                <td width="150px;" style="font-weight: bold;">StandardAccountNo</td>
                <td width="100px;" style="font-weight: bold;">Primary</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Effective Date</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">End Date</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: NewAccountGroupDetails-->
            <tr id="Model.NewAccountGroupDetails[0].AccountGroupName" rowindex="$index()" class="acctgrp-row" data-bind="click: $root.selectedRow">
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: StandardAccountNo, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].StandardAccountNo'}" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="border:2px inset;border-color:gray;">
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <input type="radio" data-bind="value: IsPrimary, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].IsPrimary'}" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:115px;">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: EffectiveDate, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].EffectiveDate'}" readonly="readonly" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:115px;">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: EndDate, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].EndDate'}" readonly="readonly" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ContractType, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].ContractType'}" />
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: CompanyID, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].CompanyID'}" />
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: AccountGroupName, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].AccountGroupName'}" />
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].IsSelected'}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2" style="text-align:right;">
        <input type="button" value="New" data-bind="click: addNew" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" data-bind="click: remove" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new AccountGroupViewModel());
});

     function AccountGroupViewModel() {
    var viewModel = this;

    //Convert Model property into observable array for KO
    var rawList = '@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.NewAccountGroupDetails))';
    viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails = ko.observableArray(convertJSONToKoObservableObject($.parseJSON(rawList)));

    //Add properties to the vm and an empty ko object to the array
    viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails.push(newAccountGroupDetail());

    viewModel.addNew = function () {
        viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails.push(newAccountGroupDetail());
    }

    viewModel.remove = function (row) {
        viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails.remove(function (item) {
            return item.IsSelected();
        });
    }
}

function convertJSONToKoObservableObject(json) {
    var ret = [];
    $.each(json, function (i, obj) {
        var newOBJ = {};
        for (prop in obj) {
            newOBJ[prop] = ko.observable(obj[prop]);
        }
        ret.push(newOBJ);
    });

    return ret;
}

function newAccountGroupDetail() {
    this.StandardAccountNo = ko.observable('');
    this.IsPrimary = ko.observable(false);
    this.EffectiveDate = ko.observable(new Date());
    this.EndDate = ko.observable(new Date());
    this.AccountGroupName = ko.observable($('#txtAccountGroupName').val());
    this.ContractType = ko.observable($('#ddlContractTypes').val());
    this.CompanyID = ko.observable($('#ddlCompany').val());
    this.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a simple fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I have updated the JS for the viewmodel with the comments from below. It does remove a row but the issue is it is not removing the selected row..if you check the last row, say out of 5, it'll remove all of them. If you check the first 4 but not the 5th, it won't remove any... WTH!

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of mistakes here

```
viewModel.selectedDetails = ko.computed(function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails(), function (row) {
            row.IsSelected(true);
        });
    });
```

This piece of code `row.IsSelected(true);` is actually **set** `IsSelected` observable value to true.

To remove item from ObservableArray you should use something like:

```
viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails.remove(function(item) {
    return item.IsSelected();
});
```

Also to convert json value to viewModel, take a look at the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: The problem is the remove function is bound to the top level viewModel which contains an array property to populate the page. The remove event is tied to this top level and not to the items in the list. This means when the remove is fired, its removing the array itself and not the row since its not at that level. Let me know your thoughts..